# SBT - Adding custom resolver is not working

Tags: scala, maven, sbt, amazon-redshift

I am trying to import redshift JDBC into my project . Based on this link 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html
My sbt build doesnt seem to pick this resolver . What am i doing wrong 
Below is my sbt settings

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
      scalacOptions ++= compilerOptions,
      logLevel := Level.Debug,
      resolvers ++= Seq(
        "Redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"
      )
    )
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole build.sbt file and also the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))

scalaVersion in ThisBuild:= "2.12.7"

resolvers += "redshift" at "http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release"


libraryDependencies += "com.amazon.redshift" % "redshift-jdbc41" % "1.2.10.1009"
```